# Boolean not inheriting

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

I created a boolean method in a super class, but when I call on that method to use it in the sub class, it is giving me a type mismatch error saying it can't convert a boolean to A. I'm probably missing something minor, but is there another way to use the method in an inherited class?

```
public class A{
    public boolean Proper(String expression){
    //body of method that determines if an expression is proper
    return true;
    }
}



public class B extends A {

    static BalancedExpressions Proper = new BalancedExpressions();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/Expressions.txt"));
                FileWriter output = new FileWriter(new File("Output.txt"));

                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();

                    output.write(nextLine + "\t");

                    //following line is giving the error
                    if(Proper = true) {
                    output.write("proper" + "\n");
                    } else { 
                    output.write("improper" + "\n");
                }
                scanner.close();
                output.close();
                    }
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }//end main

    }
```

Comment: "error saying it can't convert a boolean to A". I would think it complains about that it can't convert it to BalancedExpressions, but hey, could you please post the entire error?

Comment: - Type mismatch: cannot convert from BalancedExpressions to boolean
 - Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write `Proper("some string")`, not `Proper`. If you write it with parantheses, it's a function call; if you write it without then it's your `BalancedExpressions` variable. Also you need to use double equal signs `==`. The line you're currently using tries to assign true to the `Proper` member variable. Also, you don't need to write `if (something == true)`, just do `if (something)`

Answer (score 1):

Okay yeah you've just got a typo lol.

```
                //Proper is already a boolean, so this would work perfectly,

                if(Proper(nextLine)) {
                output.write("proper" + "\n");
                } else { 
                output.write("improper" + "\n");
```

You were setting proper to true, and not making a method call